# In the $αβγ$ cosmology paper, how do the authors assume the integral of density over time in the early universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, density, elements

In the famous [Alpher-Bethe-Gamow paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803), the authors say: "it is necessary to assume the integral of $\sigma_n dt$ during the building-up period is equal to $5 \times 10^4 \frac{\text{g sec}}{\text{cm}^3}$"

How do they determine this integral of density over time of the early universe?